# Action decorator with API view in Django is not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created following API view.

```
class LandingFlowViewSet(APIView):
    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def get_mobile_number(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(('ok'), status=200)
```

urls.py

```
 path('landing-flows/', views.LandingFlowViewSet.as_view()),
```

request format :- /landing-flows/get_mobile_number/

I am getting 404 error.It is working fine with model view set.

Answer (score 5):

`APIView` has no action (it's something specific to `ViewSet`)

As said by @*xordoquy* in this issue

> https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6515